# Error Code 1010 in CloudFlare

Tags: ssl, https, dns, certificate, cloudflare

I'm trying to deploy a site in cloudflare by going into

Crypto `>` create `>` cert `>` RSA `>` enter my domain name `>` submit.

I kept getting

> Error Code 1010

I've already tried

`Settings->CloudFlare Settings->Browser Integrity Check->Toggle Off`

and reattempt, I got the same result.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Yep, worked for me also. And to readers in 2022, that initial Settings page is now under the Firewall menu option on the left.